# Stream Compression - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: java

For one of my projects, I'm wanting to compress a data stream and transmit over a socket. What I've done so far is

```
        echoSocket = new Socket(SERVER_HOST_NAME, PORT);
        consoleIn = System.in;

        clientIn = echoSocket.getInputStream();
        clientInputUnzipper = new InflaterInputStream(clientIn);

        clientOut = echoSocket.getOutputStream();
        clientOutputZipper = new DeflaterOutputStream(clientOut);


        int r = 0, rc = 0;

        System.out.println("Connection achieved to HostName : " + SERVER_HOST_NAME + " on port " + PORT);

        while((r = consoleIn.read()) != END_OF_STREAM)
            clientOutputZipper.write(r)
```

On my client side. And it seems to be sending the first byte fine (I troubleshooted the client side to confirm this). But my reader on my server side seems to be unable to read.

```
        serverInputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        serverInputUnzipper = new InflaterInputStream(serverInputStream);

        serverOutputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
        serverOutputZipper = new DeflaterOutputStream(serverOutputStream); //used to send the data back to the client

        fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(log);
        fileFilterOutput = new FilterOutputStream(fileOutput);

        int r = 0, c = 0;

        while((r = serverInputUnzipper.read()) != END_OF_STREAM) //getting stuck on this line (waiting for input)
```

Given that I've sent through the first byte, shouldn't the serverInputStream receive it? However, given it's stalled, I'd assume that it's waiting to read some data (the serverInputUnzipper.read() function). Why didn't it receive the data byte as intended?

Thanks in advance (I've spent a good portion of today trying to fix this presumably simple bug)

Comment: Are you sending just one byte and expecting it to show up on the other end?

Comment: compression works by taking a block of data, applying the analysis, doing the compression, and then writing the compressed version. internally it will have a minimum block size required before it starts writing out the compressed version.  after writing one byte, it is still waiting for more data so it can analyse this data together.  applying compression to console input isnt going to work, at least not the way you have done it. it would need to read a line at time or something and then compress that line in isolation

Comment: @SlipperySeal That's what the r = console line was meant to be doing; storing a single console line to allow for compression. Is it not doing that with the current setup?

Comment: You're reading and then writing a byte at a time. You're likely getting stuck on whatever buffering there is. first, read lines or some other sanely-sized chunk and second, flush the outbound stream when you want to actually send things.

Comment: @pvg what would that look like? I'm new to working with streams, so how would I got about extending reading to 4 bytes as opposed to the individual byte being read?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html  and review that tutorial in general. 4 bytes is kind of pointless. Well, chances are, for you application the compression is pointless too but that's a different thing. If you're unfamiliar with the apis in general, the best place to start is to get familiar with them.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this right, the InflaterInputStream on my server side reads only one byte when the read() function is called?

I don't understand why that's an issue. When I remove the deflater output stream and inflater input stream and just transmit the raw characters, no issue shows up. Why would compressing it make a difference? (or does the deflater/inflater streams write/read different byte sizes?)